# mvvmFX can't find FXML file in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, javafx, fxml, mvvmfx

I'm coding a JavaFX project with Maven and the mvvmFX Framework, on the wiki it's mentioned that you need to put all View.java and View.fxml in the same folder, but that's not possible with the Maven architecture, however it's also specified that it should work correctly with Maven as long as the path is the same in the java and ressources folders, so here is a picture of my folder architecture :
[Folder architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irmp4.png)

But it doesn't work, I have an error, it says that the ressourcepath can't find the specified file.

I tried to include different version of the dependency in the POM.xml, and I also tried to open the module to de.saxsys.mvvmfx, but that didn't work. I'm not an expert in package and module with maven so I'm trying to see if someone knows how I could repair my mistakes.

[module-info.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRAeI.png)

[Dependencies in my POM.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRVba.png)

[Error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYrJx.png)

Comment: Check the deployment folder (`target/classes` by default with Maven) and see if the FXML file is in the expected place.

Comment: It seems that the fxml file is in the same folder as the view class when I check the target/classes folder, which is not exactly the same as my current folder. There is no Ressources in the deployment folder. What should I do ?

Comment: So you have `target/classes/org/example/helloworld/TestView.fxml`?

Comment: Yes I do have this

Comment: What if you add the qualified `opens org.example.helloworld to de.saxsys.mvvmfx;` directive to your module-info file? Or even an unqualified opens directive?

Comment: Ow ! It's a victory, I still have an error, but not the same ! It's really weird, cause I tried to open org.example to de.saxsys.mvvmfx and it didn't work

Comment: Opening `org.example` wouldn't work since the resource is in the `org.example.helloworld` package.

Comment: There is also an example on how to use mvvmFX with module system and maven: https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/tree/develop/examples/jigsaw-example